# How to update .bbx file to use it in the recent version of biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, hungarian

I would like to use biblatex. I tried to set the language to hungarian. I've found a `.bbx` file, but I get strange errors if I try to use it.

The file:

```
\ProvidesFile{magyar.bbx}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{magyar}{magyar}
\RequireBibliographyStyle{authoryear}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  %\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibsstring{and}\space}

\newbibmacro{names:separator}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}%
  {\addcomma\addspace}%
  {}%
 }

\newbibmacro*{names:andothers}{%
 \ifboolexpr{%
   test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}%
   and%
   test \ifmorenames%
 }{\bibsstring{andothers}\addcomma}%
 {}%
}

\def\@magyarbbx@hun{HUN}

\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{%
  \begingroup%
    \edef\juniorpart{#7}%
    \ifx\juniorpart\@magyarbbx@hun%
      % Hungarian name
      \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#3}{#1}{#5}{\relax}%
    \else%
      % English name
      \ifnum\value{listcount}=1\relax%
        \usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
      \else%
        \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \endgroup%
}

%\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{%
% \nameprint{#1}{#3}
% \usebibmacro{names:separator}%
% \usebibmacro{names:andothers}%
% }

\endinput
```

The error:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \blx@defformat@d
```

I am not an advanced latex user, and I have no idea how should I fix this issue. I was not able to find a newer version of this file on the internet

Comment: A Hungarian localisation is currently being worked on: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/717. The file you found uses some seriously outdated code, in particular https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864. Where did you get it?

Comment: I found https://github.com/Botffy/texstuff/tree/master/tex/latex/biblatex is that your source? The files are at least three years old and one of them even has 2011 given as date. If there is no support for these files by the author any more, you should probably not use them.

Comment: I tried the solution from this answer too: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9101/161774 But I still get this error. @moewe I don't want to use them, but I have to

Comment: That answer is from seven years ago. A few things have changed since then - in its current state the files are absolutely unusable. What exactly do you need? Did someone tell you to use exactly these files? Or do you just need a Hungarian localisation for `biblatex`. If the latter is the case and you are really pressed for time you can get `magyar.lbx` from https://github.com/marczellm/biblatex/blob/hungarian/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/magyar.lbx. That file is currently under development, so there is absolutely no warranty that it gets everything right. But it is much better than what you have now

Comment: If I try than, questionmarks appear instead of quotation marks: https://i.imgur.com/UJUeiUR.png

Comment: That is because `csquotes` has no Hungarian localisation (https://github.com/josephwright/csquotes/issues/19). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166337/35864. You could try `\DeclareQuoteAlias{magyar}{dutch}` as a very dirty quick hack.

Comment: If you notice anything odd with `magyar.lbx` or have suggestions for further improvement please comment on https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/717. The thing is still work in progress, although most things should be good by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files you are using (https://github.com/Botffy/texstuff/tree/master/tex/latex/biblatex) can be traced back to [Biblatex customization: author name format defined by hyphenation (localization)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9095/35864) (and http://r.snowl.net/harvard-style-citation-in-hungarian-language-hun/). So most of this dates back to 2011 and 2012.

There were some small and some not so small changes to `biblatex` in the meantime. The most problematic change here is the change to the name formatting macros in version 3.3, see [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864).

Following [Hungarian with LuaLaTex and biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416627/35864) there was some effort to get Hungarian support into the official package. The first version of Hungarian support was worked out in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/717 and implemented in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/780. Since version 3.12 `biblatex` has included Hungarian localisation files. That means that **with a current `biblatex` version Hungarian is supported out of the box**, so you probably won't need the `.bbx` file any more.

If you load `csquotes` you also need to set up a quotation style. This is also work in progress https://github.com/josephwright/csquotes/issues/19. See also [quotation mark (quotation sign) xelatex + polyglossia + csquotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166337/35864), you probably want ([quote style as described on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Hungarian))

```
\DeclareQuoteStyle{magyar}
  {\quotedblbase}
  {\textquotedblright}
  [.05em]
  {\guillemotright}
  {\guillemotleft}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dev` branch on https://github.com/plk/biblatex now has support for Hungarian.

Comment: Just to note that this is not an official release yet and that you will net a dev version of Biber as well if you want to run the dev version of `biblatex`. I can offer no ETA on the next release version of `biblatex`, but I can warn you that it will very likely take some time if nothing urgent needs to be fixed.

Comment: Version 3.12 with Hungarian support was released in late October 2018.