# Different name order for different entries with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, babel, hungarian

I am aware that the name order [can be changed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151820/how-to-reverse-name-and-first-name) in Biblatex, but is it possible to change it entry-by-entry? I.e., to mix different name orders for different books within the same bibliography.

Motivation: for books with Hungarian authors I want to use the [Eastern name order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_name#Eastern_name_order), for the rest, the usual Western name order should be used to display authors.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9095/biblatex-customization-author-name-format-defined-by-hyphenation-localization) addresses the issue, but was discussed before Hungarian was included in Biblatex, and now that we already have Hungarian files, I'd try to avoid redifing `bbx` and `lbx` files manually.

Comment: For an Icelandic bibliography I have to order the Icelandic names by first name, e.g. "Jón Jónsson", but foreign ones by last name, e.g. "Doe, John". I accomplish this by putting the whole name of the Icelandic author in a second pair of curly brackets in the .bib file, like "author = {{Jón Jónsson}}" essentially telling Latex that it should be treated like one name. Is this what you are after?

Comment: @Plergux Thanks! Yes, I thought of this solution, but I'd try to avoid it, as it is everything but elegant... It would good to keep the nice, semantically clear usage of BibTeX.